# Which is more efficient when creating many objects together in php?

Tags: php, object, copy, clone

for example I want to create "obj" objects:
Approach 1:

```
$myobj1=new obj();
$myobj2=new obj();
$myobj3=new obj();
$myobj4=new obj();
```

Is creating an object and then copying it more efficient?eg.:
Approach 2:

```
$myobj1=new obj();
$myobj2=clone $myobj1;
$myobj3=clone $myobj1;
$myobj4=clone $myobj1;
```

Considering that php is  copy-on-write will I get better performance in the cases that $myobj1 and  some other obj is never used on run-time? Will I always get better performance by copying objects instead of creating them?

Comment: The two examples are not the same. In the first you create 4 new objects. In the second you create *one* object and then assign it to 3 variables. In the second you would need to do: `$myobj2=clone $myobj1;` and so on.

Comment: Yap fixed it now initially I was going to ask the same question about arrays and forgot to change some content in the question but would clone do the job straight away or is it still copy on write?

Answer (score 3):

In test with 100000 cycles i had such results:

```
bin/php-test CloneVsNew
[============================================================>] 100000 u | 4399 u/s | Est: 0.0 s | Mem: 342,74 KB | Max: 367,1 KB
[============================================================>] 100000 u | 4105 u/s | Est: 0.0 s | Mem: 343,14 KB | Max: 367,1 KB
New         1,282884 sec.
Clone       1,107343 sec.
```

So, seems clone slightly more efficient way to copy objects.
Here is test code:

```
class CloneVsNew extends TestApplication
{
    final public static function run()
    {
        $repeats = 100000;
        $bar = new CliProgressBar($repeats);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $repeats; ++$i) {
            Timer::start();
            $myobj1=new \stdClass();
            $myobj2=new \stdClass();
            $myobj3=new \stdClass();
            $myobj4=new \stdClass();
            Timer::stop();
            $bar->update($i);
        }

        self::addResult('New', Timer::get());

        $bar = new CliProgressBar($repeats);

        Timer::reset();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $repeats; ++$i) {
            Timer::start();
            $myobj1 = new \stdClass();
            $myobj2 = clone $myobj1;
            $myobj3 = clone $myobj1;
            $myobj4 = clone $myobj1;
            Timer::stop();
            $bar->update($i);
        }

        self::addResult('Clone', Timer::get());
    }
}
```

Tested on:

```
php -v
PHP 5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2013 16:20:31) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Other php versions can show other results.

**Update:**

For the test used [php-bench](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench) tool.

Comment: `clone` is basically just a C `memcpy`, so it makes sense that it would be a little faster. The difference is negligible, though, and would only be relevant if you are cloning a massive amount of objects...

Comment: @alexander-yancharuk +1 for your test Although I get unstable results with 100000 (the fastest is sometimes new sometmes clone because the difference is negligible and different resources are allocated each time) I realised that as the difference is negligible  Sverri M. Olsen is right. Because there is not much difference, memcpy could happen straight away  without having to wait for changes, but I haven't seen any memory usage increase on system monitor which might be because the objects don't contain any data. I 'll have to check with populated objects when I have free time.

Comment: I 've done it with 99999999 objects (hoping that most of the time they ll get the same resources) I got:
**New:506.75122475624
Clone:530.91913843155**

Still I am not sure if this would be the result if the objects contained some data or had operations happening in the constructor.

Comment: php -v:
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun  6 2013 11:15:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans